# Convert for loop to streams using java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

Need ideas for converting below loop into streams. I am new to java 8 streams and learning practically how it will implemented.

```
for (int i=0; i < headerNames.size(); i++){
    XSSFCell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
    cell.setCellValue(headerNames.get(i));
}
```

Comment: you create a cell, set its value, and lose it, that's it with the code?

Comment: @Naman I *assume* ... the newly created cell belongs to the headerRow. So it is *not* lost.

Comment: Why do you want to convert this to a stream? Not everything should be a stream. Just because streams are a new tool in your toolbox, doesn't mean you should use it for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below snippet,

```
IntStream.range(0, headerNames.size())
         .forEach(i -> headerRow.createCell(i)
                                .setCellValue(headerNames.get(i)));
```

Stream indices in headerNames and for each index create a cell and set its value.

Comment: Thanks as this has worked after the implementation.